# Double status bar problems with the view

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, statusbar

i'm about to finish my app and right now i'm doing a bit of design. I've been watchind the iOS human interface Guidelines and one pint is: "Make sure your UI can handle the double-high status bar". Most of the app runs well with double status bar, but 2 things are not working well:

- A label, when there's the double status bar disappears from the screen. Is there any way to relocate the label when there's the double status bar?
- A button: It's a button with an image, it does not disappear but it appears with wrong proportions (to put an example: original measures: 44x44; with the double status bar: 44x20). Is there any way to solve it?

The rest of the app, which is based in a Navigation Controller works well with the double status bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame of the `UILabel` and `UIButton` when the methods `application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:` and `application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:` get called.
Or if you're using Autolayout you may be able to set it up to let the UIView's (an `UILabel` and an `UIButton` in this case) move and resize correctly without any additional code.